# python array, calculate sum for all True´s

Tags: python, arrays, sum

Hi have the following arrays and I try to calculate the sum of my_array3 for all "Trues" depending on my_array1 and my_array2

```
list1 = [20, 20, 21, 25, 26, 40]
list2 = [25, 25, 29, 0, 35, 42]
list3 = [1,1,1,3,1,1]

my_array1 = np.array(list1)
my_array2 = np.array(list2)
my_array3 = np.array(list3)

x = my_array1 < my_array2
# not correct
# x = my_array1 < my_array2.sum(my_array3)
```

i obtain the result "5" because "my_array1 y my_array2" value 3 is false. Thanks

Comment: You need to take care over what you're taking the `sum` (use parenthesis)

Comment: To be clear: you want to add up only those values from array 3, where the condition was met in the other arrays?

Comment: From the way your question is worded, I would expect your answer to be 5. What are you other value are you expecting?

Comment: @gnodab I *think* what OP is saying is that the expected result is indeed 5. The *actual* result is an error, because the `sum` method doesn't work that way.

Comment: I see. I didn't realize this was evaluated: `x = my_array1 < my_array2.sum(my_array3)`, and the source of the error

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  the result of x is array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True]), so i like to sum my_array3 (1,1,1,x, 1,1)=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the comparison, you get an array of booleans:

```
>>> my_array1 < my_array2
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True])
```

Use that as a mask, and then you can sum the result:

```
>>> my_array3[my_array1 < my_array2].sum()
5
```